# node postgres insert syntax error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to switch my psql setup over to node, and can't get the following test query to work.

```
PG = require('pg')

module.exports = class Postgres extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: =>
        PG.connect process.env.DATABASE_URL, (error, client) =>
            this.client = client

            this.sendMessage(1, 2, '3')


    sendMessage: (from, to, message) =>
        this.client.query('INSERT INTO messages(from, to, content) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id', [from, to, message], (error, result) =>
            console.log 'error', error
            console.log 'result', result
        )
```

Responds with the following error:

```
 error { [error: syntax error at or near "from"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I don't know if it matters, but here's my table.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the coffeescript btw.

Comment: Of course! Man, I am the absolute worst. Thanks Adriano

Comment: Converted my commented into an answer, so people can spot it more easily.. Cheers, August!

Answer (score 2):

I think Postgres is complaining about the [reserved keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `from` as a column identifier.

You should try double-quoting it in your query like this:

```
INSERT INTO messages("from", to, content) [...]
```